# Pros and cons to round PCB design

Tags: pcb, circuit-design, pcb-design

This is mostly out of pure curiosity, but when designing a PCB, are there any pros to going with a rounded or circular shape? I can see the obvious con of losing out on surface area for running traces or placing components, but I'm curious if there's any gain to it as well.

Any other information about how the design may be impacted electrically or mechanically is welcome. Like I said, this is mostly out of pure curiosity.

Comment: It depends whether it needs to fit into a round box, or a rectangular box, or some other weird shape like the inside of a camera body. Matching the shape of the board to the shape of the enclosure maximises the board area available.

Comment: One place round PCBs are used is optoelectronics since they can be screwed into (round) lens tubes similar optical assemblies.

Comment: @user1850479 They're very useful like that. I've also used octagonal boards in that case (cut down from something bigger) and mounted small boards on discs.  These were  for one-offs made in house, where we can only cut straight

Comment: I once worked on a hand held gadget, the circuit board was basically the shape of a gun. 

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There aren't really any pros and cons for PCB shape without additional context. If you need to fit a board into a circular device, then a circular shape maximizes the area of the board.

The most obvious con, to me, would be yield of boards in a panel. Any non-rectangular shape would leave voids in the panel which you are going to be paying for, but unable to use, in mass production.

Another potential con might be in assembly and testing. Tooling to hold the PCB during testing or assembly may be lower cost with rectangular-shaped boards, because no special considerations or changes need be made. However, as you mass-produce larger quantities, setup for such tooling becomes less significant.

Comment: Wow, yeah that seems pretty obvious in retrospect. I was more fixated on the possible electrical effects, if any, but the manufacturing side has a whole bunch of considerations

Comment: "Tooling to hold the PCB during testing or assembly may be lower cost with rectangular-shaped boards, because no special considerations or changes need be made." – My company does small-volume part manufacturing involving testing PCBAs and assembling them into parts. Some of the PCBAs are round, some are rectangular, and some are other shapes. In my experience, the shape doesn't make any difference to how hard it is to make the tooling. Of course, I don't know if my experience is typical or not.

Comment: @CassieSwett We have some unusual shaped PCBs including rigid-flex designs; compared to the "normal" rectangular boards, they can be slightly more fiddly to hold for manual soldering or other assembly steps. But we design brackets and holders regardless of the shape, so it is indeed _slightly_.

Answer (score 17):

Well, generally speaking, you make a board only round when you have to (or maybe for aesthetics). So an obvious pro is that round boards can fit in places where rectangular boards don't.

Cons of round boards:

- Low panel space effectiveness. There will be A LOT of wasted PCB area that just goes straight into the bin.
- Low board space effectiveness, because most components are rectangular in nature. You can fit more components on a rectangular board than on a round board with the same surface area.
- Round boards have to be milled which is more expensive in itself and usually also less space effective than using v-score. With v-score you don't need as much excess board material to hold your panel together.
- Probably with every single CAD tool on planet earth, routing a round board is at least a little bit more difficult, because tracks are straight lines in nature. You can try things like polar coordinate systems and round traces. But that's usually a waste of time. In most cases, the layout is simply divided into rectangular subsections. These subsections are spread out on the board and then connected together.

Comment: Lots of good information coming in on this question! Many thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Typically (at least in small to moderate quantities) you'll pay for the area of the smallest rectangle your board fits into, so a 100mm round board will cost the same as a 100mm x 100mm board. The former has area of 6940mm^2 if you allow 3mm around the perimeter, the latter 9409mm^2, so you lose more than 1/4 the board space.

It's probably worse than that in practice since components tend to be linear or rectangular and thus don't fit into an area with curved edges without more wasted space. Smaller boards (in relation to component sizes) would be worse.

The shipping weight will be reduced a bit, so there's that.

If you want  to use V-score the boards will have to be both routed and scored and the panelization will have the boards using just the same area as if they were squares of the circle diameter (square packing rather than triangular or hexagonal).
They will also have small rough flats on some or all of the edges.

There's no particular issue for modern PCB manufacturers to make round (or indeed elliptical) circuit boards without much (if any) additional charge but it may not be the most convenient in general. For some applications such as mounting inside sensor heads (such as the below, image from [here](https://www.indiamart.com/proddetail/thermocouple-head-16778269062.html)) it is necessary unless you can fit everything on a much smaller rectangular board of an area that can be inscribed inside the circular cavity.

[image]

If it's just for looks, you can round the corners off and have a board that's a bit more pleasant to handle and perhaps fits inside a housing with curved inside corners such as an Altoids tin (like the Beaglebone Black).

Comment: Lots of good information coming out of this question and this response! Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 3):

I would like to add to this question from our perspective as a PCB assembly company. So this is regarding the actual manufacturing of your product.

To assemble the bare PCB, all PCBA companies will put your individual PCB into a panel of multiple PCBS. On one hand, this is to reduce the handling times (like buying a carton of 12 eggs instead of individual eggs), on the other hand, this is to make it possible to run the PCB on automated conveyors during assembly. Generally speaking, most companies will want to have a 10mm frame around the panel without components to make sure the PCB can be transported on conveyors and to have sufficient surface area to clamp the panel in the various assembly processes (paste printing, pick-and-place).

Having a round design limits the PCB assembler in how they can connect the individual board to this panel, and it ultimately limits the ways in which the depanelization can happen later. We like to panelize PCBs with V-Cuts instead of tabs (also called catwalks). This is because the panel connection is quite stable during assembly and can quickly be separated with a machine that runs a blade over it to cut the boards out of the panel. If you have a round PCB, there are limited options to connect the PCB with a v-cut. If you add perforated tabs, those might be in the way during your assembly unless the depanelization was done with a very precise milling process.

If you would like to have a round shape overall, I found it best to straighten out the edges of the PCB. You lose a bit of surface for routing, but you ultimately enable your PCB assembly house to chose whatever panelization method best fits your quantity.

Here is an example image I just drew up:

[image]

A: Round PCB
B: Round PCB with straightened edges
C: Example of panel connection with straightened edges

A final consideration is efficient material usage of PCB base material. While this is not such an important consideration with small volumes or double sided standard PCBs, wasting PCB base material can have a punishing effect on your final product price for very high layer counts or special PCBs such as metal core PCB or rigid-flex PCBs where the cost of the base materials are a significant factor of your PCB price.

EDIT - Updated PCB panel based on Spehro Pefhany's comment:

[image]

Comment: +1 but typically inside corners should have a minimum radius of 1mm, 0.4mm at €xtra co$t. The former corresponding to a cutter diameter of 2mm, of course.

Comment: Great point! I would add a small cross pattern in the center that looks like the outside panel frame. It can be kept at something like 5mm width. This would allow the PCB manufacturer to mill into this center cross without added cost, and the added material cost would be marginal while increasing the overall stability of the panel.